# Enable button if local storage variable exists

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show edit/delete buttons when local storage is not empty.

in my view.html I try:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">     
     <button ng-disabled="localStorage.getItem('wimmtkey') !== null"  > Edit</button>
</div>
```

then in `review.controller.js`
I have this function:

```
function submit() {  
    if($rootScope.name!=null)    {
        var temp={
            "name":$rootScope.name,
             "surname":$rootScope.surname,
             "email":$rootScope.email
        }
        $scope.localArray.push(temp);
        localStorageService.set("wimmtkey", $scope.localArray);
        $scope.obtained_array = localStorageService.get("wimmtkey"); 

        var Results = UniversalService.PostReview(JSON.stringify(JSONObject));
        }
    }
```

but the button is shown always visible even when I go incognito. What problem could it be?

Comment: localStorage.hasOwnProperty('wimmtkey') is better pratice, anyway.

Comment: are you setting the local storage in the incognito tab? if not, when you go into incognito mode after you set it, it wipes it out.

Answer (score 0):

The button will always be shown because you're using `ngDisabled` instead of `ngShow`, `ngHide`or `ngIf`. `ngDisabled`, when it evaluates to `true`, simply means the button is unclickable.

As I can see from the condition, the button will get disabled when the `wimmtkey` item exists in `localStorage`. That seems like the opposite of what you're trying to accomplish, judging from your description.

Also, are you adding `localStorage` to the `$scope` object? Your code doesn't show this and you can only use it in the view if it exists as `$scope.localStorage`. If it doesn't, the condition will never evaluate to `true` (because it actually throws an error that is silenced by Angular) and the button will never be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a wrapper for localStorage.wimmtkey:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">     
    <button ng-disabled="LS_wimmtkey!==null">Edit</button>
</div>


var MainController = function($scope) {
    $scope.LS_wimmtkey = localStorage.getItem('wimmtkeys');

    $scope.$watch("LS_wimmtkey", function() {
        localStorage.setItem('wimmtkeys', $scope.LS_wimmtkey); 
    });
};
```

In your function submit you must use $scope property:

```
function submit() { 
    //your code is here
    $scope.LS_wimmtkey = $scope.localArray;
    //your code is here
}
```